# Why is my AJAX file download, using Blob based object URLs, corrupting files?

Tags: javascript, ajax, download

I need to build functionality to allow users to download files from an authenticated REST service. The GET request for the file has to be made with an "Authorization" header set to an oauth access token. I have no problem making this request through AJAX using the superagent library but converting the returned file to a downloadable link is problematic. Here is what I'm currently using to try this.

```
api.getFile(file.name, function (err, res) {
    var windowUrl = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    var blob = new Blob([res.text], {type: res.type});
    var dataUrl = windowUrl.createObjectURL(blob);
    callback(dataUrl);
});
```

I request the file. Get the correct window.URL object based on the browser. Create a blob with the file contents that get returned as res.text and the mimetype that's returned as res.type. Use the windowUrl object to create an object URL from the blob. The callback then saves this data url so I can create a link like so.

```
<a href={file.dataUrl} download={file.name} target="_blank">{file.name}</a>
```

This strategy works fine for simple text based file types like .txt or .json but is causing issues for more complicated types. A png after going through this process won't open and throws a generic corruption error. I also tried with a PDF and it opens and has the correct number of pages but the content is blank.

I have also verified that the REST service is not causing the corruption by downloading various files through curl.

Any ideas what might be happening? I'm also open to other strategies for authenticated file downloads if there is a better option.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get authenticated downloads working through a different strategy. Instead of making a request for the file contents, when a user clicks a download link a request is made for a single use access token to download that file. The token is then set as a query parameter on the file url which is then automatically triggered to download using

```
window.open(url);
```

My particular problem is solved but I am still curious if there is a way to use my previous strategy without corruption issues.